# How to generate a reliable synthetic key based on unreliable user-entered data?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

friends! My problem for you today is this: I'm working with a shared Excel file which several employees in my company edit to track work done using one of our tools. Every day, I'll grab the latest version of this file, scrub the bajeezus out of the user inputted data, and then load it into our MySQL database for use with our BI tools.

When I insert that data into the database, I'm using an auto-incrementing integer primary key to identify each record (as one should do). But my dilemma is this: this primary key does absolutely nothing to prevent me from inserting the same record from the Excel file multiple times. I could insert the same row numerous times and MySQL would just happily accept the clone and keep incrementing the integer.

*Obviously*, I have really good discipline about not inserting the same row twice, but if I fall down an open manhole and die, I'd like this process to be safe enough that someone picking up for me couldn't possibly run into this issue.

So, I want to try to come up with a natural key from the user-input that will help me uniquely identify every record in the dataset so that I can never insert the same row twice. Problem is, all of the columns in my dataset aren't always present, even the ones that would conceivably make for good natural keys on their own and, also, this being user-entered data, there's going to be a high rate of error in the data being entered.

So, what I want to know is: what are the best practices for creating a good, reliable, uniqueness-enforcing key when the data you're inserting isn't giving you much to work with? Cyclic-redundancy checksums? Chopping together a UUID generator in Power Query?

Comment: Have you considered tracking the source records for your data? And keep track of which ones have been used in the current data used? You can consider identifying the input records by giving them a unique id or using a 'hash' of some input fields to allow you to track where the records were used. Lots of ways of doing this. see Audit trail of preventing multiple processing of the raw input.

Comment: You need to provide more information about your data schema. Generally, you might be able to add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 columnA, columnB, columnC, ...)` to your `INSERT` query, but without any examples, it's hard to suggest something.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent: The thought had crossed my mind. It would be trivial to add a row-counter formula to the excel table. The problem is that the Excel sheet is worked on through Web Excel, which doesn't allow cell locking. So, there would be no way to protect that column from meddling. Plus, if any rows are deleted, it would break the formula.

Comment: @daShier: I'm less interested in a solution for this specific dataset and more interested in a general recommendation/best practice for whenever this kind of scenario comes up in the future. The WHERE NOT EXISTS is a really good trick, though, and I'm kicking myself for not thinking of that earlier. :)

If you have any other good practices like that, consider submitting them as an answer.